# should CMake add_executable include header files?

Tags: c++, cmake, header, include

I'm pretty new to CMake, and my question is:

say we have a simple project with only

```
main.cpp
```

that uses

```
header.h
```

And i want to build this project using CMake, so i have a minimal 
CMakeLists.txt that only contains the following (only what's relevant):

```
add_executable(MyApp main.cpp)
```

Is there a reason to include the `header.h` in the `CMakeLists.txt`?

From what i've seen, if i modify the `header.h` and run `cmake` again, 
it update as expected.

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate, as the linked question is about `add_library` command (in contrast with the title).

Answer (score 1):

> should CMake add_executable include header files?

I don't know if this applies to all compilers, but as far as GCC/Clang are concerned: It doesn't matter. You don't need to, but it doesn't break anything if you do.